# Intentionally distorted/misaligned graphics?

Tags: gui-design, design

Recently, I saw this circulating on social media:
[image: skewed Google graphics]

I think the image speaks for itself. If it doesn't, the Google image is askewed, and the caret seems to be intentionally off-centered (aligned a bit nearer to the top).

I downloaded the Google logo and tried to check it myself. I also checked out Google Chrome.

It turns out the post is legit.

Is there a specific reason for this? Since this is the UX SE, is there a specific reason for Google to do what they did to the text caret?

Comment: This question might be suited more for [GD.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com). My best guess regarding the logo: a bit of variance and imperfection is more interesting and human (even for a giant software company).

Comment: @Alan Yeah, I actually thought about that. An imaginary coin flip decided otherwise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Grphic Design

Comment: Can't speak to the text caret, but typography involves a lot of optical compensations; perfect geometry often looks wrong:  http://typographica.org/on-typography/making-geometric-type-work/   The adjustments to the G aren't accidental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironically, graphics that are tweaked -- especially letter forms -- look more correct than those that are geometrically perfect. For example, letters that are round on the bottom extend beyond the baseline, but the whole line of text looks even. Those that appear to be a uniform thickness all around are often not. And, as you point out, ones that look perfectly round have been adjusted to be visually right.

[Here's an article](https://medium.com/@lukejones/optical-adjustment-b55492a1165c) that describes these and other adjustments graphic designers make.